# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (For my friend it works fine.)

Tags: javascript

For my friend the code works fine.

```
function saveProfession(profession)
{

    fetch('/game/saveProfession/' + profession).then(function(response)
    {
        if(response.status !== 200) 
        {
            console.log('problem with ajax call!' + response.status + " msg: " + 
                response.value);
            return;
        }
        response.text().then(function(data)

    }
};
```

Comment: This isn't really a service for catching typos, but you're missing a closing parenthesis on your `then()` and brackets on your last function.

Comment: @Mark_M working with AJAX and apparently it isn't supposed to have the end parenthesis I thought so as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `then()` is a function. If you open parenthesis you need to close them. Ajax is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing some code after your last "then":

```
function saveProfession(profession)
{

    fetch('/game/saveProfession/' + profession).then(function(response)
    {
        if(response.status !== 200) 
        {
            console.log('problem with ajax call!' + response.status + " msg: " + response.value);
            return;
        }
        response.text().then(function(data) { /* do something with data */ });
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't work fine for your friend.

```
response.text().then(function(data)
```

It's missing the closing `)` to the `then` statement.